# Why Sock.js use double json encoding?

Tags: javascript, json, sockjs

```
 var sock = new SockJS(url, {'protocols_whitelist': ['xhr-polling']});
 sock.onopen = function() {
     var msg = {msg: "hello"};
     sock.send(msg); // 1. example
     sock.send(JSON.stringify(msg)); // 2.example

 };
```

**1. example google chrome payload**

```
["[object Object]"]
```

**2. example google chrome payload**

```
["{\"msg\":\"hello\"}"]
```

I found that the explicit conversion to string happened in sock.js here (line 253):

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/blob/master/lib/sockjs.js#L253

that is why i see  `["[object Object]"]` when js object is sended directly(because `'' + data` converts `data` to string).

```
 that._transport.doSend(utils.quote('' + data));
```

```
SockJS.prototype.send = function(data) {
    var that = this;
    if (that.readyState === SockJS.CONNECTING)
        throw new Error('INVALID_STATE_ERR');
    if (that.readyState === SockJS.OPEN) {
        that._transport.doSend(utils.quote('' + data)); // here
    }
    return true;
};
```

**But that utils.quote does**

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L292

```
// Quote string, also taking care of unicode characters that browsers
// often break. Especially, take care of unicode surrogates:
//    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates

    utils.quote = function(string) {
        var quoted = quoteJSON(string);

        // In most cases this should be very fast and good enough.
        extra_escapable.lastIndex = 0;
        if(!extra_escapable.test(quoted)) {
            return quoted;
        }

        if(!extra_lookup) extra_lookup = unroll_lookup(extra_escapable);

        return quoted.replace(extra_escapable, function(a) {
            return extra_lookup[a];
        });
    };
```

**and finally:**

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L261

```
var quoteJSON = (JSON3 && JSON3.stringify) || function(string) {
    json_escapable.lastIndex = 0;
    if (json_escapable.test(string)) {
        string = string.replace(json_escapable, function(a) {
            return json_lookup[a];
        });
    }
    return '"' + string + '"';
};
```

As you can see that when you want to send JSON, you need to explicit call JSON.stringify by your self and the same is happened by Sock.js again on that string you passed into sockjs_instance.send.

**Why it needs to be encoded twice? The problem is i need to do some hacks on the server to decode the message, because single JSON.decode doesn't work as sock.js by default sends all as array of strings. This is performance issue.**

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see that when you want to send JSON, you need to explicit call JSON.stringify by your self and the same is happened by Sock.js again on that string you passed into sockjs_instance.send.

Websockets API assumes the data passed to "send" is text. (or binary, which SockJS doesn't support). That's why the "send" call expects it to be text.

SockJS does need to encode it sometimes, and we just happen to use json. JSON is fast (because it's often builtin). Actually, we use modified JSON encoding as you found in the code to avoid unicode issues.

Yes, in theory for some transports it would be possible to avoid double-encoding when passing rich data, but doing so is not worth the cost of breaking compatibility with native WS.

Comment: @sorry, but i still don't understand why it can't just call `JSON.stringify` (without previously enforcing the data to be string by call `''+data`) on data you pass into `sockjs_instance.send`.